# Powershell - Migrate Office 365 licensed products while retaining existing apps

Tags: azure, powershell, office365, azure-powershell

Our users are not granted access to all the apps for their licensed products in Office 365.  This is by design, and we would like to keep it that way.

Soon we will be migrating licensed products (eg Business Basic -> E3).  I would like to automate this as much as possible.

Step 1 is to retrieve the exact list of "apps" a user is assigned/enabled in O365 and temporarily store it.

Step 2 is to add the new license to that user.

Step 3 is to remove the old license from that user.

Step 4 is to restore the "apps" a from step 1, so that they have the same apps they started with.  No more, no less.

I'm stuck at Step 1.  I'm not finding an AzureAD powershell command to do this.

For Step 2 & 3, Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail and its related commands look very promising.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 can also be finished by `Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail`.

```
#List the SKUs assigned to a user
$licenses = Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail -ObjectId test@domain.onmicrosoft.com

#the first SKU is O365 E5 in my case. List its licenses (service plans)
Write-Host $licenses[0].ServicePlans
```

It's like this:

[image]

If the "apps" are assigned to the user successfully, the "ProvisioningStatus" is "Success".

You can judge whether the app is assigned successfully based on this.

Step 2 and 3 can be done with [Set-AzureADUserLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduserlicense?view=azureadps-2.0).

You may need the help of this cmd: [Get-AzureADSubscribedSku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadsubscribedsku?view=azureadps-2.0), which can list all the subscriptions (and the service plans under each subscription).